# Ruby and console output

Tags: ruby, console, tree, console-application

It is possible, generally, by means of Ruby library to output a symbol at specific location on a common Windows console screen, which seems to be 80x25 ?

The problem came up with the need to draw a specific 'tree' structure like this, for example:

```
│
├──x──y──z
│        │
│        ├──a──b──c
│        │
│        └──e──f──g
│
└──u──v──o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just interested generating trees in the console, [this post](http://tagaholic.me/2009/03/18/ruby-class-trees-rails-plugin-trees-with-hirb.html) shows you how to do it with [hirb](http://github.com/cldwalker/hirb).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper for Curses, like this [one](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rbcurse/).

Answer (score 0):

The [Win32Console](http://rubyforge.org/projects/win32console/) project should do what you want, and much more. Also, your question reminds me slightly of [Ruby Quiz #14 (LCD Numbers)](http://www.rubyquiz.com/quiz14.html).